# Thread Monitoring in c using heartbeat signals

Tags: c, multithreading, monitoring

I want to monitor threads. I used condition variables for send & receive HeartBeat & Acknowlagement signals for that.
scnMonitor_t is a monitor structure. As new threads are added it register with monitor & added to scnThreadlist_t. 
monitorHeartbeatCheck is the thread that starts with program,
monitorHeartbeatProcess is API which are added to all thread functions.

Actually my problem is that the index of process is not properly followed
It ends with a wait HB condition for 3rd Thread & dead-lock is created.
what should be the problem?
thanks in advance.

```
typedef struct scnThreadList_{
        osiThread_t     thread;
        struct scnThreadList_   *next;
} scnThreadList_t;

typedef struct scnMonitor_{
        bool            started;
        osiThread_t     heartbeatThread; 
        osiMutex_t      heartbeatMutex;
        osiMutex_t      ackMutex;
        osiCond_t       heartbeatCond;
        scnThreadList_t *threads;
} scnMonitor_t; 
static scnMonitor_t *s_monitor = NULL;

// Main heartbeat check thread
void* monitorHeartbeatCheck( void *handle )
{
        scnThreadList_t *pObj = NULL;
        static int idx = 0;
        static bool waitAck = false;

        while ( 1 ) { 
                pObj = s_monitor->threads;
        while ( pObj && ( pObj != s_monitor->heartbeatThread ) ) { //skip it-self from monitoring.
                ++idx;
                printf("\"HB Check No.%d\"\n",idx);
                // send heartbeat
                usleep( 250 * 1000 );
                pthread_mutex_lock( s_monitor->heartbeatMutex, 1 );
                pthread_cond_signal( s_monitor->heartbeatCond );    
                printf("-->C %d HB sent\n",idx);
                pthread_mutex_unlock( s_monitor->heartbeatMutex );
                // wait for ACK
                while( !waitAck ){
                        pthread_mutex_lock( s_monitor->ackMutex, 1 );
                        printf("|| C %d wait Ack\n",idx);
                        waitAck = true;
                        pthread_cond_wait( s_monitor->heartbeatCond, s_monitor->ackMutex );
                        waitAck = false;
                        printf("<--C %d received Ack\n",idx);
                        pthread_mutex_unlock( s_monitor->ackMutex );
                        LOG_INFO( SCN_MONITOR, "ACK from thread %p \n", pObj->thread );
                }
                        pObj = pObj->next;
                }
        } // while, infinite
        return NULL;
}

// Waits for hearbeat and acknowledges
// Call this API from every thread function that are registered
int monitorHeartbeatProcess( void )
{
        static int id = 0;
        static bool waitHb = false;
        ++ id;
        printf("\"HB Process No.%d\"\n",id);
        // wait for HB
        while(!waitHb){
                pthread_mutex_lock( s_monitor->heartbeatMutex, 1 );
                printf("|| P %d wait for HB\n",id);
                waitHb = true;
                pthread_cond_wait( s_monitor->heartbeatCond, s_monitor->heartbeatMutex );
                waitHb = false;
                printf("<--P %d HB received \n",id);
                pthread_mutex_unlock( s_monitor->heartbeatMutex );
        }
        // send ACK
        uleep( 250 * 1000 );
        pthread_mutex_lock( s_monitor->ackMutex, 1 );
        pthread_cond_signal( s_monitor->heartbeatCond );
        printf("-->P %d ACK sent\n",id);
        pthread_mutex_unlock( s_monitor->ackMutex );
        return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should always associate only one mutex with a condition at a time. Using two different mutexes with the same condition at the same time could lead to unpredictable serialization issues in your application.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Fapis%2Fusers_78.htm

You have 2 different mutexes with your condition heartbeatCond.

Comment: That's right, but I thought that if I use same mutex for both HB & ACS signals then they could unlock itself also & that is useless.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are experiencing a deadlock here. The thread calling monitorHeartbeatProcess() takes mutex on heartbeatMutex and waits for signal on the condition variable, heartbeatCond. While thread calling monitorHeartbeatCheck() takes mutex on ackMutex and waits for sognal on condition variable, heartbeatCond. Thus both threads waits on the condition variable heartbeatCond causing deadlock. If you are so particular in using two mutexes, why not two condition variables?

Comment: Hmm.. that's a good idea Ashok. I had tried it now but it can't stop deadlock. I think something is wrong with the logic I used.signals are sent before the wait is ready.It may be timing miss-match.

Answer (score 0):

while signalling, do not use mutex to lock. Only use mutex during wait. Means

```
pthread_mutex_lock( s_monitor->ackMutex, 1 );  ----> remove this line
pthread_cond_signal( s_monitor->heartbeatCond );
pthread_mutex_unlock( s_monitor->ackMutex );    ----> remote this line.
```

Apply where ever you have written signal.